# xcodebuild did not generate Coverage.profdata for cocospods project

Tags: jenkins, cocoapods, xcodebuild

i want to get my project's code coverage (which is managed by cocoapods), i run the following cmd :

```
xcodebuild -scheme KVODemo -configuration Debug  -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6' -enableCodeCoverage YES -workspace KVODemo.xcworkspace test
```

but i can not find the Coverage.profdata file (for normal project which is not managed by cocoapods   is under the $PROJECT_TEMP_ROOT/CodeCoverage/$PROJECT_NAME/Coverage.profdata)

i just want to know how to get the code coverage for cocoa pods  project.

Comment: Are you actually running the tests?

Comment: @quellish  yes, i can see my test cases running on the simulator,  and "TEST SUCCEEDED"  in the  terminal

Answer (score 2):

ok , after a detail look at the cmd xcodebuild , i noticed something.
here is some info in the "man xcodebuild":

```
xcodebuild -showBuildSettings 
            [-project name.xcodeproj | 
            [-workspace name.xcworkspace -scheme schemename]]
```

the $PROJECT_TEMP_ROOT i mentioned in my question is the result of

```
xcodebuild -showBuildSettings |grep PROJECT_TEMP_ROOT
```

and this should the same as the xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -project xxx.xcodeproj

because my project is managed by cocoa pods, so i should get the $PROJECT_TEMP_ROOT  in this way :

```
xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -workspace xxx.xcworkspace -scheme xxx
```

and finally , find the Coverage.profdata in the $PROJECT_TEMP_ROOT/CodeCoverage/$PROJECT_NAME/Coverage.profdata